# Answered puzzle with correct answer, got downvoted

Tags: discussion

Is [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46309/coin-splitting-game/46322#46322) common here? Basically I took some time to think to an answer, analized it (I think correctly), and foudn the answer, also I noted that most people assumed that the number of coins in game is the same when a offer is rejected (making reasonings like: "If B reject then A get at least 4 coins). I then did the riddle again with a friend and we came again to that conclusion. Meanwhile the OP is gone and won't accept it anyway.

Edit in the mean while my answer got so many downvotes that it was deleted (partially hided, so I marked myself to delete it anyway), so I posted it again ^^ this time hopefully noone is going to downvote it (the answer is still the same^^). Why so much effort to keep a correct answer alive?)

Comment: It's alright to delete an answer that's been heavily downvoted, but in the future, please don't repost an identical answer. If you want to use answers this way, a separate answer should substantively change the meaning or result. Otherwise, please edit the answer instead.

Comment: Sorry but the asnswer was correct, why should I change it? I just rephrased it in a different way, but I won't drop a correct answer just because it is heavily downvoted

Comment: Downvoting keeping goin on.

Comment: If you don't have substantive changes to make to an answer, then don't delete it and re-post it to reset its score. I'm not going to judge whether or not it's correct, but it may be worth thinking about why people might downvote it.

Comment: Don't worry about scores in general. There were probably 100 users seeing your answer, but only 1 or 2 of them decided to downvote. That is actually not that bad. It happens from time to time that users got frenzy and downvote to hell an answer because..., well, simply because it has already a big negative score. It is a herd thing.

Comment: @Emrakul is correct. The point of voting is to make **some indication of a post's quality** immediately evident to readers; deleting and resubmitting an identical post prevents people from getting that indication, and goes against how the SE system is supposed to work. Instead of 'cancelling' the votes, you should ask *why* people downvoted your answer (as you've more or less done here). If I were him, I would consider deleting the new answer and undeleting the old one (unless you've since edited them to be substantially different, of course).

Comment: The current answer is of good quality i fixed it  and is substanially differennt, but beside providing the current correct answer and having been re-readed several times it is still being downvoted ^^

Comment: The thing is that VOTING SHOULD BE OF QUALITY INDICATION, BUT IT ISNT!. This is a SE major problem I see more and more people complaning about that, the site is losing appetibility to me. Actually there's no incentive in putting answers anymore due to high chance of getting downvoted ^^. You should need an alternating vote system (in example a way to vote things that are wrong for actually the reason for which are wrong and need to be fixed before becoming visible)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your answer was downvoted because others thought it was (1) wrong and (2) badly explained, and perhaps also because (3) they didn't like your accusations that everyone else was misunderstanding the question.

I agree with them (with the proviso that the question doesn't make it clear enough what all parties' actual preferences are), though as it happens I didn't downvote your answer. I'm not sure this is the best place to explain why, but it's not clear where's better so here goes. (Mods, let me know and/or just delete this if this is inappropriate; I can see that we might want to discourage relitigation of questions from the main site in Meta.)

You say that the best A should do is to offer A3/B5 at the outset, because that's an offer B can't refuse, because if B refuses he necessarily gets <5 coins in the end.

It's true that if A offers A3/B5 at the outset then B should accept, and therefore that A can get 3 coins that way. But if both A and B are, as stipulated, "rational" then A can do better.

I take it the questioner's intent is as follows. Both A and B want as many coins as possible. Each prefers, *subject to that*, for the other to get as few coins as possible. Both are very clever, both know both are very clever, both know both know both are very clever, etc.

So, if that's the case, we proceed backwards.

- With only 1 coin on the table, "whoever makes the offer takes the coin" (this is stated explicitly in the question). (It will be B to play.)
- With 2 coins on the table and A to play, if A offers X2/Y0 then clearly B will refuse (because then it will be B's turn with just one coin). If A offers A1/B1 then again B will refuse (because B prefers A0/B1 from the 1-coin game to A1/B1 from the 2-coin game). So whatever happens A isn't getting any coins. And A prefers A0/A1 to A0/A2, so A will make an offer B will refuse and the final result will be A0/B1.
- With 4 coins on the table and B to play, we know from the above that if A refuses B's offer then the result will be A0/B1. Therefore, A will take any offer of 1 or more coins at this stage (but will refuse an offer of A0/B4, of course); therefore, B will offer A1/B3 and A will accept.
- With 8 coins on the table and A to play, we know from the above that if B refuses A's offer then the result will be A1/B3. Therefore, B will take any offer of 4 or more coins but will refuse an offer of A5/B3. Therefore, A will offer A4/B4 and Y will accept.

That's if the players are "nasty" and each prefers (if their own outcome is fixed) for the other to get fewer coins. What if they're "nice", so that each still primarily wants as many coins as possible but now prefers the other to get *more* subject to that?

- With only 1 coin on the table, "whoever makes the offer takes the coin" (this is stated explicitly in the question). Again, it will be B to play.
- With 2 coins on the table and A to play, if A offers A2/B0 then clearly B will refuse (because then it will be B's turn with just one coin). If A offers A1/B1 then B will accept (B now prefers this to the A0/B1 that would result from refusing). So clearly A will do this.
- With 4 coins on the table and B to play, we know from the above that if A refuses B's offer then the result will be A1/B1. Therefore, A will take any offer of 2 or more coins at this stage, or an offer of 1 coin that gives B more than 1. In particular, A will accept A1/B3 but not A0/B4; so B will offer A1/B3 and A will accept.
- With 8 coins on the table and A to play, we know from the above that if B refuses A's offer then the result will be A1/B3. Therefore, B will take any offer of 4 or more coins, or any offer of 3 or more that gives A more than 1. So A will offer A5/B3 and B will accept.

So, with "nasty" players the final outcome is A4/B4; with "nice" players the final outcome is A5/B3. *In neither case is A3/B5 the best that A can do*.

Now, of course B could try to get a better result out of A, e.g. by saying "I promise that I will refuse any offer you make that's worse for me than A3/B5", and then we get into the thorny issue of players trying to restrict their own options for their own good. In that case the result depends on exactly what ability each player has to restrict their own options. A could say "I promise that if you threaten to refuse things that are good for you, I will call your bluff" and if B takes this seriously then he won't make the threat above because that would result in B being worse off than if he accepted A's initial offer of A4/B4. In the absence of anything in the question to indicate that we're meant to consider such shenanigans (and to nail down what such shenanigans are actually possible -- precommitment is difficult...), I think it's clear that we aren't.

Comment: You explained that well, byt I do not agree, I'm editing to explain (on the original post where it makes sense). Actually your answer is the only one the I would vote up. the further, however if players could actually speak to each other I would agree on that. Anyway obsessive downvoting of other users without explaining reasons of downvote is not helping anyway. If I can keep stats I can be sure there's a raise in downvotes recently.